# Как фильтровать ввод с клавиатуры?

Tags: java

Пишу консольное приложение.. как я могу отфильтровать ввод с клавиатуры, так чтобы в нельзя было водить ,наример, цифры?
(Посимвольная валидация, или как-то так)

Да да, фильтрование на лету, чтоты если юзер нажимает кнопку, которая вводит недопустимый симво, то символ не отображался, и ввод не изменялся.

Comment: Регулярные выражения?

Comment: Именно регулярные выражения, само собой. Сравнение ввода с заданной  маской. Только вот старайтесь вопрос поконкретнее задавать, а то на такой вопрос всегда будет ответ из трех-четырех слов, так как ответ очевиден.

Comment: Посимвольная валидация

Comment: обычно нет смысла. Все равно найдется человек, который придумает, как ввести нужный символ. Лучше получать ввод и потом его анализировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея это именно фильтрование на лету - то есть когда вводится с клавиатуры значение, но некорректное просто не набирается?

Для оконного приложения вешаете обработчик на компонент (примерно как [тут](http://java.about.com/od/Handling-Events/ss/A-Keylistener-Example-Program.htm))

Для консоли - стандартного решения нет. Можно попробовать поиграться с потоком System.in, но в ряде случаев там может оказаться не консоль, а именно поток ввода.
Есть довольно старая и вроде даже неплохая библиотека [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net).